# Losing my padding

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website and everything works perfect in google chrome but in IE and firefox I lose my content padding when the browser resizes below 800px.

http://www.readysetpixel.net/about.html  is the web address.  If your screen is bigger than 800px in height it will show the padding their at the bottom of 20px but when you resize your screen IE and FireFox just ignore the padding.

Would there be a reason for this?  I have tried so many different things Im goin nuts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are explicitly setting the max-height to 490px. If you have such a requirement where you are targeting devices, you should use media-queries instead. Is there a reason for using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
     if ($(this).height() <= 800){
      $('.content').css('max-height', '490px'); //sets max-height
     } else{
      $('.content').css('max-height', ''); //deletes max-height
   }
 }).resize()
})
</script>
```

at the bottom of the page. I also see you dont have meta-port view tag so obviously are also not doing responsive design. Getting  rid of the script at bottom(above), you should be set.

Comment: How do I get the same effect using a media query for .content.  I tried but I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: This is what I used just now but it does the same thing.  @media screen and (max-height: 800px) {
  .content {max-height: 490px;}
}

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: you need to use metaport view tag to get media query working

Answer (score 0):

You may try a `min-width` for your `body` or some parent selector in CSS like;

```
body{
  min-width: 800px;
}
```